# No new line in terminal ubuntu after changing prompt style

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I changed the PS1 for terminal to

```
export PS1="\033[0;33m\h:\W \u\$ \e[m"
```

Now, it doesn't type into new lines in case of a long sentence. Instead, it just overwrites on the existing written stuff in the same line.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax must be:

```
PS1="\[\033[0;33m\]\h:\W\u\$\[\033[m\]"
```

Or if you prefer to use `\e` instead of `\033`:

```
PS1="\[\e[0;33m\]\h:\W\u\$\[\e[m\]"
```

Your problem in missing `\[` with the `\e`  ASCII escape character `(033)`

[image]