# Long input in terminal doesn't change to new line

Tags: command-line, docker, tty

When I type a long command line like `dddddddddddddddddddddddddddd` here, the command will overwrite the last line without changing to new line.

I first use `SSH` to connect to the host, then `docker exec -it 525d5808c4a9 bash` to the docker container.

Here is the `PS1` variable of the container.

```
root@525d5808c4a9:/home/mhtan/git/pytorch-pretrained-bert/examples# echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
dddddddddddddddddddhome/mhtan/git/pytorch-pretrained-bert/examples# dddddddddddd
```

A similar question is [No new line in terminal ubuntu after changing prompt style](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646374/no-new-line-in-terminal-ubuntu-after-changing-prompt-style), but that does not solve my case.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: Try `echo "$PS1" | grep $'\e'` to check for raw escapes in the PS1. Hopefully it won't find anything.

Comment: @wjandrea Terminator + `oh my zsh` before ssh to the host

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, that gives me no output

Comment: Try checking out [How do I get long command lines to wrap to the next line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24358/301745) and the related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal size in Docker is [a known issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33794), and the quick fix suggested works for me:

```
docker exec -e COLUMNS="`tput cols`" -e LINES="`tput lines`" -ti container bash
```

The `COLUMNS` and `LINES` variables tell the shell and other commands what the size of the terminal is. They seem to be unset in a docker terminal, so you set them manually.

I think you can also use the `$COLUMNS` and `$LINES` variables instead of `tput cols`/`tput lines`.

```
docker exec -e COLUMNS="$COLUMNS" -e LINES="$LINES" -ti container bash
```